# How to match and replace everything after a specific word until it reaches comma in a list of strings using python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a DataFrame with list of strings as below

```
df

text
,info_concern_blue,replaced_mod,replaced_rad
,info_concern,info_concern_red,replaced_unit
,replaced_link
```

I want to replace all words after info_concern for eg. info_concern_blue/info_concern_red to info_concern until it encounters comma.

I tried the following regex:

```
df['replaced_text'] =  [re.sub(r'info_concern[^,]*.+?,', 'info_concern,',
           x) for x in df['text']]
```

But this is giving me incorrect results.

Desired output:

```
replaced_text

    ,info_concern,replaced_mod,replaced_rad
    ,info_concern,info_concern,replaced_unit
    ,replaced_link
```

Please suggest/advise.

Comment: If it encounters comma, I want it to stop matching further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['replaced_text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'(info_concern)[^,]*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpC9RV/1).

If you want to make sure the match starts right after a comma or start of string, add the `(?<![^,])` lookbehind at the start  of the pattern:

```py
df['replaced_text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'(?<![^,])(info_concern)[^,]*', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpC9RV/2). *Details*:

- `(?<![^,])` - right before, there should be either `,` or start of string
- `(info_concern)` - Group 1: `info_concern` string
- `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than a comma.

The `\1` replacement replaces the match with Group 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the pattern `info_concern[^,]*.+?,` matches till before the first comma using `[^,]*`

Then this part `.+?,` matches at least a single character (which can also be a comma due to the `.`) and then till the next first comma.

So if there is a second comma, it will overmatch and remove too much.

---

You could also assert info_concern to the left, and match any char except a comma to be removed by an empty string.

If there has to be a comma to the right, you can assert it.

```
(?<=\binfo_concern)[^,]*(?=,)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\binfo_concern)` Positive lookbehind, assert info_concern to the left
- `[^,]*` Match 0+ times any char except `,`
- `(?=,)` Positive lookahead, assert `,` directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H1QpDN/1)

If the comma is not mandatory, you can omit the lookahead

```
(?<=\binfo_concern)[^,]*
```

For example

```
import pandas as pd

texts = [
    ",info_concern_blue,replaced_mod,replaced_rad",
    ",info_concern,info_concern_red,replaced_unit",
    ",replaced_link"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(texts, columns=["text"])
df['replaced_text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'(?<=\binfo_concern)[^,]*(?=,)', '', regex=True)

print(df)
```

Output

```
                                           text                             replaced_text
0  ,info_concern_blue,replaced_mod,replaced_rad   ,info_concern,replaced_mod,replaced_rad
1  ,info_concern,info_concern_red,replaced_unit  ,info_concern,info_concern,replaced_unit
2                                ,replaced_link                            ,replaced_link
```